# What is the value of out field in System class?

Tags: java, system.out

i understand that out is a field in System class and it reference some object of PrintStream as `print(System.out.getClass());` returns class java.io.PrintStream.

also i presume declaration of out in System class should be something like `public static PrintStream out;`

My query here is what actually is the value of 'out' field in System Class.
it can not be like
`public static PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out);`

Just Curious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you check the source code of `System` class, you can see it is set via native method calls:

```
 private static native void setOut0(PrintStream out);
```

Comment: frankly speaking, i don't know where to look for source code of System class on my pc. started learning java just a month ago. i would be thankful if u could teach me how to do that or any reference regarding that. i'm on linux ubuntu and running java 7 update 25

Comment: @Shashi Java is open-source, just do a google-search with the terms "System class source code".

Comment: @Shashi  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java#System.setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29

Comment: @Shashi in your JDK installation directory you have a file `src.zip` which contains the source code of the standard Java classes.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of out is like this (taken from System src)

```
public final static PrintStream out = null;
```

and it is initialized in this method

```
private static void initializeSystemClass() {
    ...
    setOut0(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fdOut, 128), true));

...
```

which is called by JVM

Answer (score 0):

`out` is a **static** member in the `System` class and is an instance of `PrintStream`.
From [System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) class

```
public static final PrintStream out;
```